# Estilizar un select option cuando ya está seleccionado

Tags: html, css

La cosa es que cuando le añado el CSS a un `option` se aplica solo con el dropdown. Entonces, me gustaría que apareciera también una vez se muestra el `option` en la casilla del `select`.

```js
function showInp(){
  getSelectValue = document.getElementById("telprefix").value;
  if(getSelectValue=="and"){
    document.getElementById("andphone").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("andphone").setAttribute("required", "required");
    document.getElementById("espphone").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("frphone").style.display = "none";
  }else if(getSelectValue=="esp"){
    document.getElementById("andphone").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("espphone").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("espphone").setAttribute("required", "required");
    document.getElementById("frphone").style.display = "none";
  }else if(getSelectValue=="fr"){
    document.getElementById("andphone").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("espphone").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("frphone").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("frphone").setAttribute("required", "required");
  }
  else if(getSelectValue===""){
    document.getElementById("andphone").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("espphone").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("frphone").style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.form-group {
 padding: 20px;
 letter-spacing: 0.1px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 
}

.title-form {
 color: gray;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.form-control{
 border: none;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #727272;
 width: 100%;
 height: 30px;
 
}

.form-control-phone, .form-control-option {
 float: left;
 border: none;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #727272;

}


.form-control-phone {
 display: none;
 height: 30px;
 margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
 <label class="animated-label title-form" for="phone"><i class="fas fa-phone-square"></i> Teléfon de Contacte *</label><br>
 <select name="telprefix" id="telprefix" class="form-control-option" required onchange="showInp()" style="width: 90px; height: 33px; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
  <option value="" class="title-form">--Prefix</option>
  <option value="and">+376</option>
  <option value="esp">+34</option>
  <option value="fr">+33</option>
 </select>

 <input id="andphone" class="form-control-phone" type="text" pattern="^[8|7|3|6]\d{5}$" />
 <input id="espphone" class="form-control-phone" type="text" pattern="^[9|8|7|6]\d{8}$" />
 <input id="frphone" class="form-control-phone" type="text" pattern="^[1|2|3|4|5|6]\d{9}$" />
</div><br>

<div class="form-group" style:"padding-top: 20px;">
 <label class="animated-label title-form" for="message"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i> Missatge *</label><br>
 <textarea id="message" class="form-control" name="message" style="max-width: 100%; min-width: 100%; min-height: 150px; max-height: 100%"></textarea>
</div>
```

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Comment: Como puedes hacer que? Cual estilo quieres aplicar? En que momento precisamente?

Comment: El primer parámetro, por ejemplo, tiene un estilo, el de --Prefix, pero solo se muestra cuando se muestra el dropdown, no cuando lo selecciono.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si quieres aplicar el mismo estilo de los elementos `option` en el select, nada mas tienes que, en tu caso, aplicar la misma clase al `select` como tal; ya que son dos elementos por separado, cada uno con sus estilos.

```js
function showInp() {
  getSelectValue = document.getElementById("telprefix").value;
  if (getSelectValue == "and") {
    document.getElementById("andphone").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("andphone").setAttribute("required", "required");
    document.getElementById("espphone").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("frphone").style.display = "none";
  } else if (getSelectValue == "esp") {
    document.getElementById("andphone").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("espphone").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("espphone").setAttribute("required", "required");
    document.getElementById("frphone").style.display = "none";
  } else if (getSelectValue == "fr") {
    document.getElementById("andphone").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("espphone").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("frphone").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("frphone").setAttribute("required", "required");
  } else if (getSelectValue === "") {
    document.getElementById("andphone").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("espphone").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("frphone").style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.form-group {
  padding: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 0.1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.title-form {
  color: gray;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.form-control {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #727272;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
}

.form-control-phone,
.form-control-option {
  float: left;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #727272;
}

.form-control-phone {
  display: none;
  height: 30px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="animated-label title-form" for="phone"><i class="fas fa-phone-square"></i> Teléfon de Contacte *</label><br>
  <select name="telprefix" id="telprefix" class="form-control-option title-form" required onchange="showInp()" style="width: 90px; height: 33px; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
    <option value="" class="title-form">--Prefix</option>
    <option value="and">+376</option>
    <option value="esp">+34</option>
    <option value="fr">+33</option>
  </select>

  <input id="andphone" class="form-control-phone" type="text" pattern="^[8|7|3|6]\d{5}$" />
  <input id="espphone" class="form-control-phone" type="text" pattern="^[9|8|7|6]\d{8}$" />
  <input id="frphone" class="form-control-phone" type="text" pattern="^[1|2|3|4|5|6]\d{9}$" />
</div><br>
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!

Comment: No hay porque :) si te sirvio recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada con el check